# append link to struts2 tree tag

Tags: tree, struts2

I have a tree structure data that I want to load dynamically using `<s:tree>` of struts2. It loads completely ok. the problem is it's just for displaying, I can't figure out a way to make each item a link or append a link to it or anything. So there is no way to add new node somewhere deep in tree easily. Does anyone have any idea how to append link to treenodes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. I modified tree and treenode tag library and added "treeOnClick" attribute to them. So now I can specify this attribute for static definition of tree and I added "nodeLinkProperty" for dynamic tree definition. If someone needs it I can upload codes.